# Determine the values of x to make this matrices not work in inverse

Tags: matrices

\begin{pmatrix} x(x^2-1) & x \\ 
    3x      &  1 \end{pmatrix}

This is a $2\times 2$ matrix $M$.

Determine the values of $x$ for which $M^{-1}$ does not exist (Inverse)

I figured that $0$ and $2$ would work since it wouldn't inverse because both of these are zero determinants. Would any other numbers work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The matrix is not invertible if and only if its determinant is zero. So find all values of $x$ for which the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of the matrix is $x^3 -3x^2 -x$.  This is zero when $x=0$ or when 
$$
x = \frac{3\pm \sqrt{13}}{2}
$$
Those are the only three values of $x$ for which the matrix is not invertible.

When $x=2$ the determinant of the matrix is $-6$ not zero.

Comment: You're right I made a mistake on the 2! Thanks for spotting that out. With x=3+/-sqrt(13)/2. If I use these to substitute into x, im still not getting 0? Am I just not substituting it right